# preposition and relative pronoun - good at

Tags: relative-pronouns

> If there's one thing koalas are good at, it's sleeping.

Can I change this sentence to "If there's one thing at which koalas are good" or "If there's one thing that koalas are good at"?

Comment: They are all fine. The first and third are the same, with optional "that" omitted in the former. The one with "at which" is formal and less likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the relativizer ***that*** is an entirely optional stylistic choice in such contexts (but probably we usually *don't*, if only because on average we don't bother with unnecessary words).

The other (more extreme) rephrasing is also perfectly valid - but again it's unnecessary circumlocution to include the relativizer ***which*** (*and* relocate the preposition ***at***), so it would be far less common.

Answer (score 0):

> If there's one thing koalas are good at, it's sleeping. ✅
>
> If there's one thing that koalas are good at, it's sleeping. ✅

---

> If there's one thing at which koalas are good, it's sleeping.

That is grammatically correct but I can't imagine anyone saying or writing it these days except as a joke.